# How does Testflight improve app distribution?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a customer who is using an app on their iPads that was developed by a third party who is no longer around.  The app is not in the AppStore.  They were explaining to me how once a year they need to login to TestFlight.com to reset something.  I looked at Testflight at as far as I can tell, its a testing platform, not for production use.  I assume they are renewing the dev certificates or something similar.

Does this make sense? Is this a legal way of running a native app on an iOS device?

What are the benefits of services like TestFlight?

Comment: What's with the down votes? Did I ask something wrong?

Comment: Typical StackOverflow. The question is good, but SO tends to mod down questions that they consider too simplistic. I for one would have loved to know about these services two years ago.

Comment: Also don't begin posts with "I'm new here."

Comment: the "I'm new here" part was to explain the newbieness of my question.  I'm familiar with SO, just not with the iOS dev world. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your Enterprise Certificate

Enterprise apps must be re-provisioned once a year. You will need to login to the Apple Dev Center, refresh your Provisioning Profile, resign the app, and re-upload to TestFlight.

#### TestFlight And HockeyApp

In addition to [Testflight](https://testflightapp.com) there is also [HockeyApp.net](http://hockeyapp.net). These are services that allow you to manage an app either during test using Ad Hoc certificates from Apple or acting as a managed AppStore when developing Enterprise apps.

It also has a number of great features, including, crash report collection, managing of testers and their feedback, update notifications on the client, test device UDID management, and verifying that the tester has actually installed the correct version.

All these things are incredibly useful to someone that has to deal with these sorts of things professionally.

#### Enterprise vs. Ad Hoc

Enterprise certificates from Apple allow you many of the same privileges as the AppStore. This arrangement requires you to be a business with a DUNS number and you must sign a contract with Apple that states you will use this exclusively in adherence to their terms. This costs about $299/year and the app is good for one year once correctly signed. You can install it on any iOS device in accordance with the contract you signed with Apple.

Ad Hoc is what is used for in-house testing. Each device UDID has to be added to the Apple Developer Portal, attached to the provisioning profile, downloaded, and resign the app with the new provisioning profile. Cost is $99/year, maximum of 100 devices, and devices can only be removed once a year. Each app expires after a few months.

Comment: They didn't mention anything about paying Apple annually, they said that the just "reset something" so it sounds like they are not 100% legit.  If the original dev is not around (someones friend of a friend type of thing) and they don't have access to the Apple dev account, what can they do to ensure that things keep working?   Also they asked if I could make some changes to the app, I assume without the source code from the dev, they are SOL.

Comment: @Kerberos42 From the Xcode Organizer for archived apps you can resign the app without recompiling.

Comment: @Kerberos42 I believe that reset is non-technie-speak for resign the app. They will need to install the newly signed version once a year. Ideally you would have the source code, access to the Enterprise Developer account, and admin access to TestFlight. You will want to make sure you archive, sign and upload the IPA and dSYM file to TestFlight. The dSYM file allows you to decode the crash logs.

Answer (score 1):

Test Flight is an apk/ipa (app binary) distribution mechanism. So they may be accepting testflight's profile on their phones if their UDID was registered to receive drops of a particular app.

Answer (score 1):

TestFlight can be used for distributing apps signed with Enterprise Certificates, i.e. apps that can't be distributed through AppStore.

Another possibility is that the app is run on only a few devices, registered as test devices on a regular Developer Account. If that's the case, the limit of numbers of devices should be noticed: 100 devices.

Comment: One of the questions they had for me was how do they add a new iPad? Is this something that is done in testflight?  I'll be onsite in two weeks, so I'll have a better idea then.

Comment: If they're using enterprise certificates, they only need to add it to TestFlight. If they're using regular test slots, they need to add to Apple Developer Portal, add to a provisioning profile and add the profile to TestFlight, besides adding the device to TestFlight.